# What is the best practice for upselling features?

Tags: features, pricing, packaging

I’m trying to add a new feature to improve our product in the site.
Currently I have this:

- Explain the specific features of the product and price packages.
- Display an order summary on the right hand side of the page:

[image: mockup for the above points]

**If I want to add the new feature here, where would be the best place to put it?**

I was thinking it could go either inside price packaging, the order summary or on the next page?

What do you think? Do you have a more effective way to explain the different features and price plans for a product?

Answer (score 1):

Separating the contents of the product from the summary like this is rather confusing. Especially since you're now making it rather difficult to compare the content. The thing you want to do is to show what people are missing out on if they don't select the optimal plan (the one you want to push).

There's multiple ways to steer the user's decision making.

**Emphasize benefits**
The more focus you bring to the benefits and features, the more value users will feel they're getting for their money. Strike through features that are 'missing' from certain plans. This helps with comparing benefits for your user, but works in your favor.

**Use a decoy**
If you want to upsell, use decoy products. This is slightly bordering on manipulation, but it hooks on people's tendency to compare products relatively to one another.  Add a product with the same price or higher price point than the one you want to sell, but give it less features.

[image: Decoy effect]

**Place the price plan left to right, not top to bottom**
Also start with the highest and least desirable one and work your way towards the cheapest options. The other way around and people won't consider your more expensive plans. This works hand in hand with the natural reading order. Highlight the price plan you want to sell.

[image: Price plan order]

This article shows some best practises to optimise the price plan.
http://uxmovement.com/content/7-design-strategies-for-a-successful-pricing-table/

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment :). One more thing:  Where do you recommend I put this new upselling feature? Thanks!

Comment: I'd integrate it in your current design for product plan displays. If you're unsure you'll get the results you want, you can always A/B test it and see how it compares. Examples for how it could look are in the link :)